# How to check if toast is present

Tags: typescript, ionic3, toast

I want to check if toast is present if it is than I want to move the cart button

here a screenshot how it looks now:

[image]

How can I move the cart button up when the toast is present? Or even the whole page has to move up.

I tried this:

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
        message: 'Dish added to Cart',
        cssClass: 'mytoast',
        duration: 2000
      });

      toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
        console.log('Dismissed toast');
        document.querySelector('.fab').setAttribute('bottom', '10px');
      });

      document.querySelector('.fab').setAttribute('bottom', '60px');

      toast.present(toast);
    });
```

But that is not working

Comment: 1) Turn on toaster 2) after 10 minutes, if you don't smell anything, toast is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just forget to pass the style to `setAttribute` so here is the answer:

```
let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
   message: 'Dish added to Cart',
   cssClass: 'mytoast',
   duration: 2000
});

toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
   document.querySelector('.fab').setAttribute("style", "bottom: 10px;");
});
toast.present(toast);
document.querySelector('.fab').setAttribute('style','bottom:60px');
```

Comment: Make sure to set this as the answer, so other users can use your answer.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
(document.querySelector('.fab') as HTMLElement).style.bottom = '10px';
```

on dissmiss and

```
(document.querySelector('.fab') as HTMLElement).style.bottom = '60px';
```

on create.

Comment: style does not exist on type Element

Comment: @Sreinieren I edited, maybe it's not the cleanest way, but try just to see if it works